# How can I free memory in the running Memgraph instance?

Tags: memgraphdb

I know that by setting the `--memory-limit` flag in the Memgraph configuration file (`/etc/memgraph/memgraph.conf`) I can set the maximum amount of memory that a Memgraph instance can allocate during its runtime.

I've limited the amount to a pretty low value since I'm running a fair share of Docker images at the same time.

Is there a way to run a memory cleanup from Memegraph Lab on my Memgrap instance? I've never run out of RAM, but I'd just like to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run a memory cleanup by running the `FREE MEMORY` query. After importing dataset for a few times, memory can be fragmented form the import + delete. Calling `FREE MEMORY` should defragment the RAM that Memgraph is using.